# What do you call each part of a piecewise function?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, piecewise-continuity

Let $(\phi_i)_{1\leq i\leq m}$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, and set

\begin{equation}
f=
\begin{cases}
\phi_1 &\text{ if *case 1*}\\
\phi_2 &\text{ if *case 2*}\\
\vdots & \vdots \\
\phi_m &\text{ if *case m*}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is it correct to say, **"$f$ is a piecewise function with $m$ pieces"** Or is there a different term to refer to each line above? By "piece" I mean both the pair of $\phi_i$ and * case i *

Also: **Is there a name to refer to the individual functions $(\phi_i)$?** e.g. would it be proper to say "$f$ is a piecewise function, where each piece is continuous?"

Comment: Usually piecewise is used along with continuous, so that each of the $\phi_i$ is continuous over it's domain of definiton, but in total $f$ may not be

Comment: A "case definition with $m$ cases"?

Comment: *Piece* is fine.

Comment: You are right (both times).

Comment: @JCAA  It seems ambiguous, since "the $i$th piece" can refer to either the function $\phi_i$ itself, or the function-case pair. Are there any common terms to distinguish between the two?

Comment: A piece is a function together with its domain.

Comment: Piecewiseness is not a feature of a function at all. It is a feature of _this particular definition_ of the function; there might be others. I'd go with "case".

Comment: It is called "piece" when Neretin's group is discussed https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/jraimbau/2018/06/14/the-neretin-groups-bruno-duchesne/&ved=2ahUKEwjCt8fKq6DqAhVEhOAKHWFZDjIQFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0vllHH1d4oLCZwTMu3HQ0P